# what does "not even related to..." mean?

Tags: meaning

I read a sentence:

> Not even related to my leukemia my cardiologist had me undergo an MRI to assure that I did not have arterial issues.

How am I to understand the first half of this sentence?

Comment: Have you used a dictionary? Those are basic words used in their usual meaning.

Comment: @Helmar I think we can waive the usual rules given that someone may be struggling to understand a medical report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not even related to", in this context, means "nothing to do with". Your cardiologist wanted you to have an MRI scan to see if you have any problems with your arteries (blood circulation). It had nothing to do with (not related to) the fact that you have leukemia.